# How to make a layer show up only in the last page in ConTeXt's letter module?

Tags: context, letters, layers

Sorry for the long explanation, but here it goes: say you have a >=3 page document, and you need to put a layer *only on the last page*. And yes, you have your ConTeXt installation up-to-date.

[On the wiki seems to say this could be achieved with the `state` option](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layers#State). It says the following:

> The available options for the "state" of a layer are:
>
> - `start`: layer appears only on the current page
> - `stop`: layer doesn't show up
> - `repeat`: layer prints on all pages
> - `next`: layer appears on the following page
> - `continue`: layer appears on all pages except the first

As `state=start` is the default option, one can imagine setting `state=stop` at the beginning and `state=start` somewhere on the last page could do the trick. So a first approach to this could be the following:

```
\definelayer[mybg][width=\pagewidth,height=\pageheight,x=0mm,y=0mm,state=stop]
\setlayer[mybg][]{\framed{\red Layer}}
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=mybg]
\starttext
\input ward
\page[yes]
\input tufte
\page[yes]
\setuplayer[mybg][state=start]
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

But, turns out, this won't work. That layer didn't showed up anywhere! You even could try setting again `state=stop` at the beginning, and `state=next` somewhere on the penultimate page:

```
\starttext
\input ward
\page[yes]
\setuplayer[mybg][state=next]
\input tufte
\page[yes]
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

But again, the layer didn't showed up anywhere. For the sake of not being so messy and keeping settings out of text, a last resort could be throwing all background settings inside a `\startsetups`-`\stopsetups` environment, and calling it at the last page:

```
\startsetups background
\definelayer[mybg][width=\pagewidth,height=\pageheight,x=0mm,y=0mm,state=start]
\setlayer[mybg][]{\framed{\red Layer}}
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=mybg]
\stopsetups
\starttext
\input ward
\page[yes]
\input tufte
\page[yes]
\setups{background}
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

**This did the trick**. Yikes! Now, I'm trying to do the same with a `letter` - with a custom letter layer. Of course, you'd think of using `letter`'s module dedicated commands instead:

```
\usemodule[letter]
\setupletter[address={ABC.DEF}]
\startsetups backaddresslayer
\defineletterelement[layer][backaddress][backaddressinfo]{\framed{\correspondenceparameter{address}}}
\setupletterlayer[backaddress][state=start,alternative=backaddressinfo,x=0pt,y=0pt]
\stopsetups
\starttext
\startletter
\input ward
\page[yes]
\input tufte
\page[yes]
\setups{backaddresslayer}
\input knuth
\stopletter
\stoptext
```

But, contrary to the expected, `backaddress` layer won't show up anywhere...

I don't know if this is some *PEBCAK* mistake, a bug or something. I'd be glad if you could help me a bit by pointing it out.

Cheers! :)

Comment: define the `layer`, and then throw it in `setups` as shown in the scratch-paper answer below

Comment: @doed - Layer is defined with `\defineletterelement`. It's named "backaddressinfo", heredated from `letter`'s "backaddress" element.

Comment: You can repeat the layer on each page (`state=repeat`) and check for the last page with `\doif{\subpagenumber}{\lastsubpagenumber}{...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked at the letter module (I don't use it, so it will take me some time to understand what it does under the hood), but here is a suggestion for the first problem that you describe.

The difficulty comes because you are trying to toggle the state of the layer from `stop` to `start`. IMO, it is easier to permanently set the state of the layer to `start`, and then simply set the content of the layer on an appropriate page.

Now, to set the content of the page on the last page automatically, you need to know the page number of the last page (`\lastcountervalue[userpage]`) and you need to be able to typeset content on arbitrary page (`\startpostponing`). Combining these, we get:

```
\definelayer[mybg][width=\pagewidth,height=\pageheight,x=0mm,y=0mm,state=start]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=mybg]

\startpostponing[{\lastcountervalue[userpage]}]
  \setlayer[mybg]{\framed[foregroundcolor=red]{Layer}}
\stoppostponing

\starttext
\dorecurse{3}{\input knuth \page}
\stoptext
```

As expected, this shows the word `Layer` on the top left corner of the third page.

Comment: @doed: You misunderstood my answer. I am not saying that 'don't use letter unless I say so'; I am simply saying that I don't know how the letter module works under the hood, so I don't know how to place a layer on a particular page using letter module. [I realize that I omitted **I** from `I don't use it` that led to the confusion. My apologies; fixed now]

Comment: thanks Aditya. That's exactly how I interpreted the sentence: "unless I tell you, don't use it" or "don't use it if I don't tell you", or "unless I don't tell you, don't use it."